# react-native-video-controls Warning Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. in React-Native 62.2

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native to develop the Android APP ,I am using `react-native-video-controls` in my app after upgrading React_native from 60.0 to 62.2 .

I am getting error
 **Warning Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified**.  in React-Native 62.2 for react-native-video-controls

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';

import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';


 <View style={{ width: "100%", height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#065535' }} >
                  <VideoPlayer
                      navigator={this.props.navigator}

                      source={{ uri: "https://howtags.com/" + items.file_Name }}
                      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, position: "absolute" }}

                      ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref }}
                      resizeMode="cover"

                      posterResizeMode="cover"

                      fullscreen={true}
                      onEnd={this.onEnd}

                      onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart}
                      onProgress={this.onProgress}
                      paused={this.state.paused}

                      onFullScreen={this.state.isFullScreen}
                      volume={10}
                    />

    </View>
```

I am getting this error only after upgrading to "react-native": "^0.62.2", If anyone know the solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is now patched. Use `react-native-video-controls: ^2.5.0`

Comment: Thank you for the reply  but still i am getting the same error

'Warning Animated: useNativeDriver was not specified'

Comment: Sir please check the package once still i am getting the errors and its not working properly

Comment: sir please help me to solve the warning and check my code once .
Thank you.

Comment: There are some errors in 2.6.0
While playing the video its taking too much time to load some times videos are not playing and pause ,

Comment: Please submit any issues on github.