# Warning Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified in React-Native 62.2 for react-native-video-controls

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react-native to develop Video sharing Android APP ,I am using react-native-video-controls in my app after upgrading React_native from 60.0 to 62.2 .

I am getting error
Warning Animated: useNativeDriver was not specified. in React-Native 62.2 for react-native-video-controls

My Code:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';

import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';


 <View style={{ width: "100%", height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#065535' }} >
                  <VideoPlayer
                      navigator={this.props.navigator}

                      source={{ uri: "https://howtags.com/" + items.file_Name }}
                      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, position: "absolute" }}

                      ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref }}
                      resizeMode="cover"

                      posterResizeMode="cover"

                      fullscreen={true}
                      onEnd={this.onEnd}

                      onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart}
                      onProgress={this.onProgress}
                      paused={this.state.paused}

                      onFullScreen={this.state.isFullScreen}
                      volume={10}
                    />

    </View>
```

I am getting this error only after upgrading to "react-native": "^0.62.2",

I am posting this question second time because last time i didn't get any answer for my question

If anyone know the solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.62, not setting `useNativeDriver` prop for `Animated` component will show you this warning. Since one of the libraries you're using seems to use Animated without explicitly setting this prop to true or false so you get this warning.

I don't think you have much to do with this problem, just wait for an update to this library where contributors correct this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for the suggestion  ,

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate: [react-native-video-controls Warning Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. in React-Native 62.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709022/react-native-video-controls-warning-animated-usenativedriver-was-not-specifie)

> I revived this library here:
> https://github.com/criszz77/react-native-media-console
>
> Fixed all the issues I could find + added TypeScript support. Should
> be easy to migrate.
>
> Hope this helps anyone...